# Display function result to html

Tags: javascript, html, function, dom

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <label for="start">start</label>
    <input type="date" name="" id="start" />

    <label for="end">end</label>
    <input type="date" name="" id="end" />
    <button onclick="abc()">btn</button>
    <div id="pos">
      <p>duration:</p>
    </div>
    <script src="tes.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

```js
let tes1 = [];
function abc() {
  let start = document.getElementById('start').value;
  let end = document.getElementById('end').value;

  let blog = {
    start,
    end,
  };
  tes1.push(blog);
  console.log(tes1);
  console.log(blog);
  takeTheTime(start, end);
  renderPost();
}

function renderPost() {
  document.getElementById('pos').innerHTML = '';

  for (let i = 0; i < tes1.length; i++) {
    document.getElementById('pos').innerHTML += `
      <div id="pos">
      <p>durasi :${takeTheTime(start, end)}</p>
    </div>
      `;
  }
}

function takeTheTime(start, end) {
  let result;
  let one = new Date(start);
  let two = new Date(end);
  

  if (one < two) {
    result = two - one;
  } else if (result == undefined) {
    return alert('eror');
  }

  let msecond = 1000;
  let secInHours = 3600;
  let hoursInDay = 24;

  let distanceInDays = Math.floor(result / (msecond * secInHours * hoursInDay));
  let distanceInMonth = Math.floor(result / (msecond * secInHours * hoursInDay * 30));
  let distanceInYears = Math.floor(result / (msecond * secInHours * hoursInDay * 30 * 12));
  if (distanceInDays == 1) {
    return `${distanceInDays} Day`;
  } else if (distanceInMonth > 12) {
    return `${distanceInYears} Years`;
  } else if (distanceInDays >= 30) {
    return `${distanceInMonth} Month `;
  }  else if (distanceInDays > 1) {
    return `${distanceInDays} Days`;
  } 
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wfobn.png)I'm having trouble with javascript. I made a website that calculates the start date and end date, where the values of the start date and end date are taken from user data. I was able to make the calculation as a function, but I am confused about how to display the results on the web. Maybe you guys can help, thanks in advance:) I have also included javascript and html code.

Comment: Can you show your HTML code please?

Comment: @User456 Already... :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of smaller erros which keep your date from being shown.

### #1

```
document.getElementById('pos').innerHTML += `
  <div id="pos">
  <p>durasi :${takeTheTime(start, end)}</p>
</div>
  `;
```

Here you call the `takeTheTime()` function with the parameters `start` and `end`. Those are local variables just valid inside the scope of the function. So the function will always return undefined. So you either need to provide the values directly e.g.
`takeTheTime(document.getElementById('start').value, document.getElementById('end').value)`

or query the values of those two input fields right inside the takeTheTime function.

### #2

```
 if (one < two) {
    result = dua - one;
  } else if (result == undefined) {
    return alert('eror');
  }
```

`dua` is not defined but I guess you meant `two`. Anyway, the second case `one > two` is missing.

If we put it together:

```js
let tes1 = [];

function abc() {
  let blog = {
    start,
    end,
  };
  tes1.push(blog);
  renderPost();
}

function renderPost() {
  document.getElementById('pos').innerHTML = '';

  for (let i = 0; i < tes1.length; i++) {
    document.getElementById('pos').innerHTML += `
      <div id="pos">
      <p>durasi :${takeTheTime()}</p>
    </div>
      `;
  }
}

function takeTheTime() {
  let start = document.getElementById('start').value;
  let end = document.getElementById('end').value;
  let result;
  let one = new Date(start);
  let two = new Date(end);


  if (one < two) {
    result = two - one;
  } else {
    one - two;
  }

  let msecond = 1000;
  let secInHours = 3600;
  let hoursInDay = 24;

  let distanceInDays = Math.floor(result / (msecond * secInHours * hoursInDay));
  let distanceInMonth = Math.floor(result / (msecond * secInHours * hoursInDay * 30));
  let distanceInYears = Math.floor(result / (msecond * secInHours * hoursInDay * 30 * 12));
  if (distanceInDays == 1) {
    return `${distanceInDays} Day`;
  } else if (distanceInMonth > 12) {
    return `${distanceInYears} Years`;
  } else if (distanceInDays >= 30) {
    return `${distanceInMonth} Month `;
  } else if (distanceInDays > 1) {} else if (distanceInDays > 1) {
    return `${distanceInDays} Days`;
  }
}
```

```html
<label for="start">start</label>
<input type="date" name="" id="start" value="2018-07-22" />

<label for="end">end</label>
<input type="date" name="" id="end" value="2018-08-22" />
<button onclick="abc()">btn</button>
<div id="pos">
  <p>duration:</p>
</div>
```

Comment: No problem syg - glad I could help! =)

Answer (score 0):

You can hook to input elements (start, end) on input. Something like:

```
let start = document.getElementById('start').value;
let end = document.getElementById('end').value;

start.addEventListener('change', () => abc())

end.addEventListener('change', () => abc())
```

Needs refinement but you get the idea

Answer (score 0):

You had some errors there. I fixed them. Hope this helps.

```js
let tes1 = [];
function abc() {
  let start = document.getElementById('start').value;
  let end = document.getElementById('end').value;

  let blog = {
    start,
    end,
  };
  tes1.push(blog);
  console.log(tes1);
  console.log(blog);
  renderPost(start, end);
}

function renderPost(start, end) {
  document.getElementById('pos').innerHTML = '';

  for (let i = 0; i < tes1.length; i++) {
    document.getElementById('pos').innerHTML += `
      <div id="pos">
      <p>durasi :${takeTheTime(start, end)}</p>
    </div>
      `;
  }
}

function takeTheTime(start, end) {
  let result;
  let one = new Date(start);
  let two = new Date(end);

  if (one.getTime() < two.getTime()) {
    result = two - one;
  }
  
  if (result === undefined) {
    return alert('Error');
  }

  let msecond = 1000;
  let secInHours = 3600;
  let hoursInDay = 24;

  let distanceInDays = Math.floor(result / (msecond * secInHours * hoursInDay));
  let distanceInMonth = Math.floor(result / (msecond * secInHours * hoursInDay * 30));
  let distanceInYears = Math.floor(result / (msecond * secInHours * hoursInDay * 30 * 12));
  if (distanceInDays == 1) {
    return `${distanceInDays} Day`;
  } else if (distanceInMonth > 12) {
    return `${distanceInYears} Years`;
  } else if (distanceInDays >= 30) {
    return `${distanceInMonth} Month `;
  } else if (distanceInDays > 1) {
  } else if (distanceInDays > 1) {
    return `${distanceInDays} Days`;
  }
}
```

```html
<label for="start">start</label>
<input type="date" name="" id="start" />
<label for="end">end</label>
<input type="date" name="" id="end" />
<button onclick="abc()">btn</button>
<div id="pos">
  <p>duration:</p>
</div>
```

`start` and `end` were undefined in `renderPost`. You also don't need to call `takeTheTime` function in `abc`.